# Content Query Webpart outputs HTML

Tags: content-query-web-part, custom-masterpage, html

I have inserted a CQWP on a site and set it to print a description, but it prints out HTML code.

`disable-output-escaping` is set to yes. That doesn't help.

Also when I try to edit it to make it print a date it says that the webpart cannot be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to disable output escaping?

```
disable-output-escaping = "No"
```

how are you doing the date?

Comment: Yes.. That didn't work either.

I am trying with this: <xsl:variable name="Created"> <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@Created) ,1033 ,'dd.MM.yyyy')" /></xsl:variable>

from http://www.uccorner.com/231/sharepoint/content-query-web-part-image-on-left-with-formatted-date-and-description/

Comment: I had to put disable-output-escaping = "yes" in the description section!